# Почему возникает ошибка 404 только под Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, firefox, firefox-extension

Есть расширение YaMuTools, которое добавляет функций для Яндекс.Музыки. Под Chrome работает как и задумано. Недавно портировал под Firefox и возникла проблема.

Один из get-запросов под Firefox возвращает ошибку 404. Все остальные со статусом 200. Под Chrome тот же запрос и тот же код работает без ошибки.
В чем может быть проблема?

Чтобы воспроизвести ошибку, установите [расширение](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/yamutools), зайдите на страницу плейлиста Яндекс.Музыки (нужно быть залогиненным) и нажмите кнопки: *YaMuTools > Фильтр треков > Вычитание треков*. Появится всплывающее окно с бесконечной загрузкой. В консоле будет ошибка 404. Полный код есть [здесь](https://github.com/Chimildic/YaMuTools/tree/firefox-v2).

Запрос совершается через `XMLHttpRequest`. Пробовал `fetch` и очистку кэш/кук - не помогло.

Firefox, 404

```
XHRGET
404
Not Found
HTTP/1.1
GET /handlers/library.jsx?owner=music-blog&filter=playlists HTTP/1.1
Host: music.yandex.ru
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
X-Retpath-Y: https://music.yandex.ru/users/music-blog/playlists/2678
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Current-UID: 224867931
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ...
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

Тот же запрос в Chrome

```
GET /handlers/library.jsx?owner=music-blog&filter=playlists HTTP/1.1
Host: music.yandex.ru
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Yandex";v="21", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"
DNT: 1
X-Retpath-Y: https://music.yandex.ru/users/music-blog/playlists/2678
X-Current-UID: 224867931
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 YaBrowser/21.9.0.1044 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://music.yandex.ru/users/music-blog/playlists/2678
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8
Cookie: ...
```

Другой запрос под Firefox

```
XHRGET
200
OK
HTTP/1.1
GET /handlers/playlist.jsx?owner=music-blog&kinds=2678&light=false HTTP/1.1
Host: music.yandex.ru
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
X-Retpath-Y: https://music.yandex.ru/users/music-blog/playlists/2678
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Current-UID: 224867931
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ...
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

Этот код отправляет запрос во всех случаях.

```js
function requestGET(url, callback) {
    requestOfType({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        formData: null,
        callback: callback,
    });
}

let countRequest = 0;
function requestOfType(data) {
    if (countRequest > 100) {
        let timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            clearTimeout(timerId);
            requestOfType(data);
        }, 1000);
        return;
    }

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    countRequest++;
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            countRequest--;
            if (request.status >= 400) {
                data.callback('error');
            } else {
                let responseJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                data.callback(responseJSON);
            }
        }
    };
    request.open(data.type, data.url);
    request.send(data.formData);
}
```

Comment: c [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) такие же проблемы?

Comment: @nazarpunk да, тоже ошибка 404 только с этим запросом

Comment: Блокировка рекламы в FF отключена? Вы в FF на Яндексе залогинены? И приведите полный код с адресом, чтоб у себя запустить.

Comment: Да, отключен. Да, залогинен. Полный код есть [здесь](https://github.com/Chimildic/YaMuTools/tree/firefox-v2). Для тестов можно установить само [расширение](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/yamutools/). Проблема воспроизводится при нажатии следующих кнопок на странице плейлиста: YaMuTools > Фильтр треков > Вычитание треков.

Comment: Настораживает что реферер не передается. Теоретически может быть такое что апишке это не нравится, и она прикидывается шлангом. Попробуй добавить `request.withCredentials = true;` междувызовами `open` и `send`, это должно включать передачу кук и добавление реферера от страницы. Еще один момент: код находится в контент-скрипте, или не?

Comment: Если с включением `withCredentials`заголовок Referer не появится, можно попробовать еще [вот это](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/webextension-xmlhttprequest-issues-no-cookies-or-referrer-solved/11224/11) - хз, актуально ли оно спустя 5 лет, но попытка не пытка...

Comment: @yar85 с `withCredentials` не сработало. Программно принудительно рефер запрещено ставить, насколько я вижу. А вот костыль пятилетней давности помог! Можете написать ответ. Желательно с пояснением что там происходит.

Comment: _«с withCredentials не сработало»_ - значит, в браузере нет автоматики (я только предполагал ее, прочтя обсуждение на MozDiscource), это ок. Сам параметр просто включает отправку чувствительных данных при корс-запросах, т.е. напрямую не связан с ситуацией. Советую попробовать через `window.content` как в ответе - MDN предлагает делать именно так, когда защита XHR/Fetch мешает... сам я не проверял, как это рекомендуемое решение работает (давно уже не писал расширений, а на проверки с репо не хватает времени). Если будут затруднения с ним, напиши в комменты к ответу, тогда гляну с репо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае, сетевой запрос из расширения Firefox не содержит заголовок `Referer`. Некоторые реализации бэкэнда проверяют значение этого заголовка (для ограничения сторонних запросов с тем же ориджином)... то есть, как дополнение к CORS, немного помогающее бороться с запросами из инъекций кода в веб-страницы.
Добавлять этот заголовок самостоятельно, перед отправкой запроса - бесполезно: в соответствии со спецификацией `XMLHttpRequest`, реферер автоматически удаляется при отправке запроса (это мера обеспечения безопасности).

##### Почему в расширениях Firefox сам не добавляет `Referer` и `Origin`

В современных браузерах, скрипты страницы и скрипты расширений выполняются в изолированных сэндбоксах, для защиты от XSS-подобных атак. Но реализация такого разделения в данный момент не стандартизирована (как и браузерные расширения в целом), поэтому разные браузеры делают это по-разному.
Firefox, в частности, предоставляет контент-скриптам расширений отдельные от контекста страницы глобальные объекты, включая объект `XMLHttpRequest` (который в расширении получает повышенные привилегии, и поэтому должен быть изолирован от скриптов страницы). Это имеет позитивный побочный эффект отправки запросов без "утечки" кроссовых кук и реферера с ориджином - что мы и наблюдаем здесь.

##### Что же с этим делать

Когда в Firefox-расширении хочется отправить запрос "от имени" странички (с автодобавлением заголовка `Referer` и возможностью использования `withCredentials` в случае кроссдоменности) - надо всего лишь получить объект `XMLHttpRequest` из контекста страницы.
Сейчас это делается так ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#xhr_and_fetch)):

```
const xhr = new content.XMLHttpRequest();
```

И современный фичедетект вариант (для кроссбраузерных расширений, ES11+):

```
const xhr = new (window.content?.XMLHttpRequest ?? window.XMLHttpRequest)();
```

В старом [обсуждении на Mozilla Discourse](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/webextension-xmlhttprequest-issues-no-cookies-or-referrer-solved/11224) (форум сообщества) можно найти еще и такой фичедетект вариант, который я тут слегка поправил:

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
  try {
    return XPCNativeWrapper(new window.wrappedJSObject.XMLHttpRequest());
  }
  catch () {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
}
// ....
const xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
```

Классическое решение использует обертку объекта `XMLHttpRequest` страницы, полученного через `wrappedJSObject` (функция `XPCNativeWrapper` добавляет безопасности: любые обращения к свойствам обернутого объекта будут игнорировать переопределения, возвращая исходные значения. На данный момент, документацию этой функции почему-то выпилили из MDN).
Учитывая то что работа с `wrappedJSObject` официально [не рекомендована](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#xhr_and_fetch) как решение - первый способ из этого ответа (с `window.content`) воспринимается более надежным, чем классический. Использование нейтив-обертки опционально, по желанию... судя по базе знаний, она вообще по большей части предназначена для XUL-документов, и у меня есть сомнения насчет "не является ли грязным хаком ее использование в контент-скрипте расширения".

Comment: Шикарный  ответ! Большое спасибо за просветительскую работу! Сколько лет вручную формировал заголовки при сканировании сайтов, а об этой особенности firefox - не знал!

Comment: @S.H., эта особенность всплывает наверное только в контент-скриптах расширений, т.к. сканеры и подобные им вещи все-таки чаще делаются с помощью фоновых скриптов (где гораздо больше возможностей, и доступен API-объект `webRequest`, через который заголовки любого запроса можно менять как угодно... в том числе и реферер переписывать).